# Problema con una funcion SELECT usando prepared statement

Tags: php, prepared-statements

estoy haciendo una funcion (`familiar_obtenerPorId($id)`) que quiero que me devuelva un **familiar** segun el `$id` que le este pasando.

```
     function familiar_obtenerPorId($id){

      include_once 'procedimientos/conexion.php';

      if (is_numeric($id)) {

         if ($con) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM familiares WHERE id  = ?";

            $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);

            $stmt->execute();

            var_dump( $stmt);

         }

      }



      return null;
    }



    $result = familiar_obtenerPorId(1);
```

No me da **errores**, el `var_dump()` de `stmt` me da lo siguiente:

```
object(mysqli_stmt)[2]
  public 'affected_rows' => int -1
  public 'insert_id' => int 0
  public 'num_rows' => int 0
  public 'param_count' => int 1
  public 'field_count' => int 12
  public 'errno' => int 0
  public 'error' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'error_list' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'sqlstate' => string '00000' (length=5)
  public 'id' => int 1
```

Y como se ve, me pone el **num_rows** = 0 , en vez de ponerme 1. He probado a hacer la misma consulta en mi BD de forma manual y si me trae el dato.

**ACLARAR** que la variable `$con` no es el problema, esta mas que probado, simplemente es la **funcion**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estas seteando el parametro en tu linea
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id); 
deberia ser
$sql = "SELECT * FROM familiares WHERE id  = ?";
$stmt->bind_param("id",$id);

o
$sql = "SELECT * FROM familiares WHERE id  = :id";
$stmt->bind_param(":id",$id);